# Why is SwiftUI behaving like this?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a dropdown menu that acts a little weird, see [here](https://imgur.com/a/3Y0MV4D).

The text updates step by step, not instantaneously, and it quivers for a little bit after being updated.

**Here is the relevant code:**

**The state variables used**

```
@State private var gender = ""
@State private var birthDate = Date.now
@State private var formattedDate = ""
@State private var genderMenuTitle = "Gender"
```

**The Form where the dropdown menu lies:**

```
Form {
    Section(header: Text("Gender")) {
        Menu(genderMenuTitle) {
            Button (action: {
                gender = "F"
                genderMenuTitle = "Female"
                print(gender)
            }, label: {
                Text("Female")
            })
            Button (action: {
                gender = "M"
                genderMenuTitle = "Male"
                print(gender)
            }, label: {
                Text("Male")
            })
            Button (action: {
                gender = "O"
                genderMenuTitle = "Other"
                print(gender)
            }, label: {
                Text("Other")
            })
            Button (action: {
                gender = "?"
                genderMenuTitle = "Rather not say"
                print(gender)
            }, label: {
                Text("Rather not say")
            })
      }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're manually updating your view every-time a user clicks the button, you can make this process smoother by using a `withAnimation` closure.

```
withAnimation {

gender = "F"
genderMenuTitle = "Female"

}
```

But I would recommend you to just use a picker instead.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var gender = "Male"
    
    var genderOptions = [
        "Female",
        "Male",
        "Other",
        "Rather not say"
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Gender")) {
                    Picker("", selection: $gender) {
                        ForEach(genderOptions, id: \.self) { key in
                            Text(key)
                                .tag(key)
                        }
                    }
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .pickerStyle(.menu)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't you particularly, but if you have a `Menu` where you change the title, which is typical, don't use the initializer `init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) where Label == Text`  rather use `init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)` like below. I also simplified things by using an `enum` to reduce the amount of state tracking:

```
struct WeirdMenuView: View {
    
    @State private var gender: Gender? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Gender")) {
                Menu {
                    Button (action: {
                        gender = .female
                        print(gender ?? "")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Female")
                    })
                    Button (action: {
                        gender = .male
                        print(gender ?? "")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Male")
                    })
                    Button (action: {
                        gender = .other
                        print(gender ?? "")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Other")
                    })
                    Button {
                        gender = .ratherNotSay
                        print(gender ?? "")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Rather not say")
                    }

                } label: {
                    // Use an actual view here. *****
                    HStack {
                        Text(gender?.rawValue.capitalized ?? "Gender")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

enum Gender: String {
    case female = "Female"
    case male = "Male"
    case other = "Other"
    case ratherNotSay = "Rather not say"
}
```

Edit:

This is exactly what I am seeing my code do:

[image]

Comment: This is good, the quivering is gone, but there is still a sort of delay. The label now updates by smoothly adding the letters which is not what I wanted. Does it do the same to you? Does it update instantly or incrementally?

Comment: See Gif above. That is standard for Menu as it will animate the change.